# Trouble cross compiling Python

Tags: android, python-3.x

I'm trying to cross compile Python 3.7.3 to run on Android. Before the updates to the NDK to remove gcc, I had been building Python 3.5.1 without any problems in this git project. https://github.com/GRRedWings/python3-android/tree/clang

The Python build recipe can be found here https://github.com/GRRedWings/python3-android/blob/clang/mk/python/3.7.3/build.sh, with many of the exports having been set in env of the root, and build_single.sh in the mk directory.

Trying to update the to the latest NDK, and running into issues, I was unable to get any support with the older version of Python.  I'm hoping that someone who understand cross compiling and configure scripts might be able to point me in the right direction.

Here is my output when I call configure

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force 
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Automake
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
OUR TARGET IS aarch64-linux-android
configure: loading site script ./config.site
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android
checking for python3.7... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for python interpreter for cross build... configure: error: python3.7 interpreter not found
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'python-3.7.3' failed
make: *** [python-3.7.3] Error 1
```

So my question is, what and where should I be focusing.  Should I be looking into the configure error saying python3.7 interpreter not found? Should I be looing in the config.log? The only error I see in there is about the interpreter.

Comment: `checking for python interpreter for cross build... configure: error: python3.7 interpreter not found`, so....do you have python3.7 installed?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, for some reason I thought you couldn't possibly need python to build python, but this is a cross compile...  I'm not past this issue

Comment: I have python3.7 installed but I'm getting the same error, any clue?

Comment: Are you sure that it's using the right version of python?

Answer (score 3):

Although it is an old question, I have solved it. It seems strange that if you do a cross-compiling, you need to install a local version of python with the same minor version. It is to say that if you want to build Python 3.7.x, you need to install a local version of Python 3.7.x on your build machine. I do it by using `pyenv`.